# IndexOutofBoundsException resolution in this given scenario

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Need to figure out the best way to get rid of the following problem of `java.lang.IndexOutofBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0`

As seen in the code, this exception is occurring anytime the condition

```
if(tempBean.getCustomerState.equalsIgnoreCase("MD")
```

is false and the outer for loop continues its execution. Which makes the code look like:

```
finalBeanOne.add(1, tempBeanOne.get(1));
```

but as finalBeanOne list never had the element at index 0 (because the if condition was false on first iteration) its throwing an `IndexOutofBoundsException`. What is the best way to fix this scenario?

```
ArrayList<BeanOne> finalBeanOne = new ArrayList<BeanOne>();

ArrayList<BeanOne> tempBeanOne = (cast) DAO.getBeanOneList();

   for(int i=0; i< tempBeanOne.size; i++ ) {

      if(tempBeanOne.getCustomerState.equalsIgnoreCase("MD") {

        finalBeanOne.add(i, tempBeanOne.get(i));
      }


  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Irrespective of the way you are checking equality, you are adding to the new array list at an 'unitialized index`. Remember that for standard array lists adding at a particular index is similar to setting at that index, in that there is a requirement that an element actually ***exist*** at that index:

```
public void add(int index,
                E element)
Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list. Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices).

Throws:
IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index > 0 || index < size())
```

To solve your problem, simply call `add` on your 'result' list:

```
finalBeanOne.add(tempBeanOne.get(i));
```

Of course, you could make your code more efficient by also using enhanced for logic:

```
List<BeanOne> finalBeanOne = new ArrayList<BeanOne>();
List<BeanOne> tempBeanOne = (List<BeanOne>) DAO.getBeanOneList();

for(BeanOne tempBean: tempBeanOne) {
    if(tempBean.getCustomerState().equalsIgnoreCase("MD") {
        finalBeanOne.add(tempBean);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Perception, you nailed it. Thats what I was trying to explain to everyone else who answered. equality is not the problem here. So simply calling add would take care of indexing?

Comment: Perception, thanks a ton. I think this would fix it. I dont have access to my machine at the moment but I'll try it out soon and accept your answer.

Comment: @user1127051 - calling `add` will insert the element in the first index in your 'result' list. If you need to preserve indexes for any reason then fill your result list before hand with a 'sentinel' value (null is your best bet). You would add as many sentinel values as are in the source list.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `equals()` method to compare `String` objects

you can simply use `add(Object)` or if you need index as key then go for `Map<integer, Object>`

Comment: Hi Jigar, thanks.. its just a quick notepad written code. I usually prefer StringUtils. But that isnt the solution to my problem here.

Comment: which line exactly throws this exception ?

Comment: This line: finalBeanOne.add(i, tempBeanOne.get(i));

Comment: Can you add an element at index 1 when there is no element at index 0? Thats the issue here.

Comment: ok got it that is the issue, but why do you need to manage indexes ?y ou can simply use `add(Object)` or if you need index as key then go for `Map<integer, Object>`

Answer (score 0):

Before starting the for loop check the size of tempBeanOne variable. Change your comparison code as below.

```
  if(tempBean(i).getCustomerState.equals ("MD") )
  {

    finalBeanOne.add(i, tempBeanOne.get(i));
  }
```

Comment: Hi Lucifer, I updated the equals condition but that isnt the culprit here.

Comment: what is tempBean's size before the loop ? have you checked it ?

Comment: Size is 2 before the for loop

Comment: Look at Perceptions answer. This wont make any difference.